# Looping user input until a positive nonzero integer is entered

Tags: java, validation, input, while-loop

I'm a complete beginner and I'm trying to trying to create a while loop that keeps asking the user for input until it gets a positive nonzero integer, and then moves on to the next part. Here's what I've got so far:

```
System.out.println("Enter the speed of the vehicle in "
            + "miles per hour: ");
    while (keyboard.hasNext())
    {
        if (keyboard.hasNextInt())
        {
            speed = keyboard.nextInt();
            while (speed <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive nonzero number: ");
                speed = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
            speed = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Right now, when I run it and enter anything other than an integer, it prints out the line "Please enter a number," but then I immediately get an InputMatchException error and the build fails. If I enter a negative number or zero, it does prompt me to enter a positive number until I do, but then the code just stops executing and keeps running while doing nothing indefinitely, instead of moving on to the part after the loop, which just starts with another system.Output. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consume the previously entered non-`int`, and then attempt to read the following input:

```java
else
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    // consume and ignore the previous non-int input
    keyboard.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for the error message. Do you have idea why it won't move on to the next block of code though? After this block there's just a blank line, and then the same thing repeats for another user input.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way. By asking for a string representation of a numerical value using the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method then applying the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex) that validates the fact that a positive numerical value was supplied (the `"\\d+"` expression), for example:

```
String speedString = "";
while (speedString.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Enter the speed of the vehicle in miles per hour: ");
    speedString = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
    if (!speedString.matches("\\d+") || Integer.valueOf(speedString) < 1) {
        System.err.println("Invalid speed value supplied!\n" 
                         + "Please enter a 'positive' non-zero number.\n");
        speedString = "";
    }
}
int speed = Integer.parseInt(speedString);
```